# Installing MSSQL for Linux on Debian Buster (SSL 1.0??)

Tags: debian, ssl, sql-server

Would love to run my MS-SQL on a Debian Buster server but there are some obstacles. First of all the installation has dependencies not available in the Buster repository, one is the old `libssl1.0.0` (and `libjemalloc1`) which hasn't been available since Debian Jessie, what the heck!?

My SQL clients have to connect to the server with encryption enabled.
Would it even be safe when the MSSQL Linux server version use `libssl1.0.0`?
It seems "SSL 1.0" can mean different things,  e.g. the SSL 1.0 protocol, which seem to be VERY insecure, another thing is about X.509 certificates, which might not be an issue, or is it? And what does `libssl1.0.0` relate too?

Is it any better to install it on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Answer (score 0):

The package `libssl1.0.0` on Debian (or Ubuntu) would refer to version 1.0.x of the Openssl library.

In terms of connectivity, I would hope that MSSQL uses TLS 1.2 (or better, but I guess if they use Openssl 1.0 that means TLS 1.2 is the best available protocol version).

Regarding the MSSQL packages, are there even packages for Debian? From what I can see the "closest" thing that exists is packages for Ubuntu 16.04.
I would say that you should install packages on an actual [supported distro (and version)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-overview?view=sql-server-2017#install), alternatively use their [docker images](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-2017&pivots=cs1-bash).

Comment: Yea, I ended up installing on SRV2016. I'll awaits MS's SQL Linux team to wake-up from their coma. Ubuntu 16.04 is old old old. One could hope they will official support Buster one day.

Comment: @MrCalvin I suppose they will have to do something regarding the packaging. However, I wouldn't be shocked if they were to just double down on docker.

Comment: Would I have these dependencies issues running SQL on Docker on Linux (and preferable on Debian Buster)?

Comment: @MrCalvin No, the docker image contains all dependencies. You would, however, need to learn how to work with Docker, where I think the persistence aspect of the setup is probably the single most important thing to figure out quickly for this type of service (ie https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-docker?view=sql-server-2017#persist ).

Comment: Look forward to get to know Docker. I wonder if I will get better RAID5 (mdadm) performance with Docker than VMs (QEMU/KVM). RAID5 only work well together with hostcache but that doesn't play well with VMs. Maybe Docker do? (a little of topic).